# IsNothing on aggregation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In the matrix of my report where there is a blank I would like to display a zero.

This is my expression

```
 =Sum(IIF(Fields!CondSubstantive.Value = True     , 1, 0))
```

I've been trying similar things to the below but not having much success

```
=Sum(IIF(isnothing(Fields!CondSubstantive.Value = True     , 1, 0)) , 0, Sum(IIF(Fields!CondSubstantive.Value = True   , 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without what datatype your field is an what your expression is intended to do (it looks like a count of non-null values?) then it's hard to give an exact answer, but this might work.

```
=VAL(Sum(IIF(Fields!CondSubstantive.Value = True , 1, 0)))
```

This just gets the result of your expression and converts it to a value. Null/Nothing/Blank/Empty String etc will all return a value of 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a parenthesis and your true value is not right

if you evaluate IsNothing() it will output true if its blank or nothing

but in your code, you are evaluating it reversely

i think the correct way will be something like this

```
=Sum(IIF (IsNothing(Fields!CondSubstantive.Value) = True, 0, 1))
```

0 is the value if CondSubtantive is nothing and 1 if there is a value existing for CondSubtantive